# Swift: JSON parsing not showing up in UILabel but can see in output window using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4

I'm new to coding and not seem to show Daily quotes to `UILabel`.
Using http://quotes.rest/qod.json
output console is showing the result but nothing is there in `UILabel`.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is JSON format from website:

```
{
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "You make a living by what you earn",
                "length": "69",
                "author": "Winston  Churchill",
                "tags": [

                    "inspire"
                ],
                "category": "inspire",

                "id": "XZiOy4u9_g4Zmt7EdyxSIgeF"
            }
        ],
        "copyright": "2017-19 theysaidso.com"
    }
}
```

Swift code I'm using to parse above JSON is:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class DailyQuotes {


    private var _quotes: String!
    private var _author: String!

    var quotes: String
    {
        if _quotes == nil
        {
            _quotes = ""
        }
        return _quotes
    }



    /// Downloading Current Weather Data


    func downloadQuotes(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){


            Alamofire.request(QuotesDaily).responseJSON 
{ (response) in

                let result = response.result
                print(result.value)
                let json = JSON(result.value!)


             self._quotes = json["contents"]["quotes"]["quote"].stringValue

                completed()
            }
             }


}
```

In `ViewConrtroller.swift` :

```
func  updateQuotesUI()
{
   quoteLabel.text = dailyQuotes.quotes
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quotes is an array

```
let arr = json["contents"]["quotes"].arrayValue
self._quotes = arr[0]["quote"].stringValue
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much boss :)